# Link between shaving body hair and weaker scalp hair

Tags: micronutrients, lifestyle, hair

I suppose this question can be addressed to both males and females, but it would be interesting to know if it varies between the two genders (hormones, etc).

I want to know if shaving body hair (chest, legs, armpit, etc...) or even facial hair (beard) has an impact on the hair in your scalp? Will it deplete the body of nutrients like keratin and vitamins that are needed in keeping a strong, healthy head of  hair? Will it **accelerate** existing hair loss resulting from androgenic alopecia (Male pattern baldness)?

Here is my hypothesis:

> Human hair needs nutrients from the blood to keep the follicle
>   healthy. If you shave body hair it will obviously  grow back, but this requires
>   nutrients. The same nutrients could have been used to go towards the
>   scalp hair and keeping it healthy and strong. But instead, more of the
>   body's resources are going towards other hairs and as a result will
>   deplete the scalp from nutrients and cause weak limp hair. And if you
>   are already predisposed to hair loss (via genetics), then this will
>   result in an accelerated rate of hair fall.

I am curious to see if anyone has done any research or if there are any studies on this. Obviously there are many *swimmers* or *cyclists* who shave their entire bodies and still have luscious strong hair which can only attributed to 'good' genetics and healthy active lifestyles. If anyone has done any research that either supports or disproves my hypothesis, do not hesitate to leave a response!

Comment: Cross-posting the same question to multiple stacks is highly frowned upon.

Comment: Hair is not living tissue (above the follicle) so how would cutting it affect anything? Hair grows at a constant rate based on age, health, genetics, drugs and toxins, and so forth. It doesn't deplete anything when it grows.

Comment: @CareyGregory I know hair is not 'living'... but in order for hair to grow, it requires the hair follicle to be nourished. If the follicle is starved from blood or nutrients in the blood, hair will not grow to be strong. It will be limp, and with time wither and the follicle will die.

Comment: Regardless, cutting hair is still just cutting dead tissue and has no effect on living tissue.

Comment: @CareyGregory yes but if you cut hair then new hair has to grow right, which requires nutrients, etc. The hair that is already grown and matured (has a life-cycle but doesn't need nearly as much nutrients from the follicle because it is like you said DEAD. I just can't fathom how that is irrelevant.

Comment: Cutting hair does not cause it to grow. It grows regardless of whether you cut it or not. A simple google search would tell you this.

Comment: @CareyGregory If you don't cut it, it will fall off on its own and eventually grow back again. I am aware of the life-cycle of hair. My issue is, prematurely cutting the hair (shaving) will FORCE the body to begin growing new hairs and thus require more nutrients than it would if I had left the hair alone. If I had left the hair alone, the body would use those nutrients when the hair falls off naturally as opposed to me forcing it to grow by shaving it... now are you starting to understand my point?

Comment: I understand your point but your premise is simply incorrect. Cutting hair does not force anything. It has no effect whatsoever on hair growth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hair structure of an adult is divided into three parts: shaft\fiber, root and bulb. Hair root is located inside hair follicles in epidermis, which itselff is growing a shaft. The shaft (what we usually call hair) consists basically of solid keratin and absent of DNA so it cannot be called "alive" in a rigorous sense ([details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair)).

Hair lifecycle consists of three stages:

- Anagen (1000 days), growth
- Catagen (10 days),  transition
- Telogen (100 days), new hair start to grow from the same folicule; old one goes out

So in fact ~90% of hair is growing at at any given time and it does not depends on hair length until follicule is damaged ([details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_hair_growth)).

However hair grows affected by external factors like nutrition and ambient temperature, lower temperature more intensively hair grow. So the imaginary situation can happen when a extremely hairy person shaves her/his body hair, the thermoisolation worsens, then he\she experience intensified hair growth.

In other words all above explanations and examples are of speculations as human body is an extremely complex system and effects of second and third order and their interactions may influence, feedback and amplify each other. In the end to regourosly answer your question there should be controlled experemint to be carried out on twins to exclude genetetic variations. I did not find such or similar experiment in literature.